# Where is PyMOL installed on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, directory, pymol

I'd like to be able to install packages for PyMOL like [eMovie](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/ISPC/eMovie_download.html) and to do so I understand I need to know where it is installed (i.e., the file directory). I installed it using Ubuntu Software Centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`which pymol` from command line will show the binairy.

Comment: This just gives me `/usr/bin/pymol` which is a program file, not a directory which is what eMovie suggests I look for.

Comment: Yes, it does. Well I assume eMovie will probably want "/usr/bin/" ;) I have seen this type of thing with other software.

Comment: Well it suggests a unique folder should exist for PyMOL, should I be able to create a new unique folder for PyMOL inside the /usr/bin directory without it disrupting the running of PyMOL?

Comment: No leave system dirs as they are. If you want a new dir create something like /opt/pymol/ :)